# working oauth2 provider server implemented on java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I am searching a working  oauth2 provider server implemented on java,
    leeloo and spring security are some that I have found,
    but there is no working example.

```
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/tutorial
https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0/wiki/Home
```

Answer (score 10):

There is the [Apache Oltu](http://oltu.apache.org) (formerly Apache Amber) implementation that supports building OAuth 2.0 Authorization and Resource Servers: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Authorization+Server and is not dependent on any framework.

You have examples of AS (Auth and Token endpoints) and RS test implementation in integration tests: 
https://github.com/apache/oltu/tree/trunk/oauth-2.0/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/oltu/oauth2/integration/endpoints

Answer (score 3):

ınside spring security package there has 2 example one tonr other sparklr implemented with oauth2

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but you could - for future references - have a look at https://github.com/OpenConextApps/apis.